# Windows 8.1 reset

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, reset

I recently had a massive crash on my Windows 8.1 partition, which has rendered it (practically) unusable. I tried to do a refresh, but the problem is, I have a Windows **8** install disk, not 8.1, and thus it didn't work. I also do not have any system restore points/backups of any sort, but I have managed to move my files off. Also, I do not know where my product key is (and cannot find it online), so a clean reinstall would not work.

My question is, is there any way to change my Windows 8 disc into an 8.1 disc to allow me to refresh/reset my PC, or is there any other way to do this (aside from repurchasing?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No problem. Do a fresh install with your 8 disk, then run windows update, which will force a  download and install of service pack 1. It's free.

Comment: I don't need a product key? 'Cause I don't have one (lost it). And by fresh install, do you mean format the partition? Or just run the disc without formatting it?